# RabbitMQ using AMQplib - Timeout for queue_declare

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I use RabbitMQ for handling logging between services (written in PHP).
If services can't connect to RabbitMQ, they timeout within 3 seconds and try to use a different method for logging. This has been tested and works well with if the RabbitMQ server is down, or behind a firewall. The code that has these timeouts appears to be the in the `AMQPStreamConnection` class of the [php-amqplib/php-amqplib](https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib) PHP package as shown below:

```
public function __construct(
        $host,
        $port,
        $user,
        $password,
        $vhost = '/',
        $insist = false,
        $login_method = 'AMQPLAIN',
        $login_response = null,
        $locale = 'en_US',
        $connection_timeout = 3.0, // here
        $read_write_timeout = 3.0, // and here
        $context = null,
        $keepalive = false,
        $heartbeat = 0
    ) {
        $io = new StreamIO(
```

Unfortunately, these timeouts don't seem to help me if I am running a massive "Purge queue" operation by clicking the button in the web UI (a queue with over 20 million in size). I wrote some code to log the times during a purge to see what was going wrong:

```
...
$this->m_queueName = $queueName;

print "creating connecton: " . time() . "<br>";
$connection = new \PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection(
    $host, 
    $port, 
    $user, 
    $password
);

print "creating channel: " . time() . "<br>";
$this->m_channel = $connection->channel();

print "declaring queue: " . time() . "<br>";
$this->m_channel->queue_declare(
    $queueName,
    $passive = false,
    $durable = true,
    $exclusive = false,
    $auto_delete = false,
    $nowait = false,
    $arguments = null,
    $ticket = null
);

print "queue declared. " . time() . "<br>";
```

The result being as follows:

```
creating connecton: 1523977606
creating channel: 1523977606
declaring queue: 1523977606
queue declared. 1523977622
hello world: 1523977622
```

I can see that the connection and channel get created, but the declaration of the queue takes way too long to respond and **I would rather the queue_declare step would timeout in 3 seconds and an Exception be thrown**. Is this possible? What configuration variable(s) do I need to change?